# Readmore.js link over text

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to get [Readmore.js](http://jedfoster.github.io/Readmore.js) to work. Everything seems to work fine apart from the link is over the text:

[image]

Here's my CSS for that part:

```css
.class-info {
    background: var(--white-color);
    box-shadow: 6px 0 38px rgba(20,20,20,0.10);
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
```

Where am I going wrong? I'm not sure if it's my CSS or the CSS Readmore.js adds.

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400">
      <div class="class-thumb">
        <img src="puy-robin/images/walking.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Walking" />
       <div class="class-info">
          <article><p class="mt-3">Walking &amp; cycling, sometimes offer the best way to see the world and appreciate the natural
          wonder and beauty of it all at a pace that suits you..</p></article>
         
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to provide html as well and enough CSS to make the necessary adjustment for this issue.

Comment: Not sure whats needed but have add the bit I think may be the part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a pseudo element before the anchor tag to create a White background behind the anchor tag to hide the texts behind it. I think it works. You need to add these CSS nothing else.

```
a[data-readmore-toggle^="rmjs-"]{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

a[data-readmore-toggle^="rmjs-"]:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 40px;
}
```

```css
.class-info {
    background: var(--white-color);
    box-shadow: 6px 0 38px rgba(20,20,20,0.10);
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Below are the CSS you need to add */

a[data-readmore-toggle^="rmjs-"]{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

a[data-readmore-toggle^="rmjs-"]:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400">
        <div class="class-thumb">
            <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/305/536/354.jpg?hmac=u9Mw37522_zEQ1FdKoVv_QXkWMkBOZFzRSXn2MCW0IY" class="img-fluid" alt="Walking" />
            <div class="class-info">
                <article><p class="mt-3">Walking &amp; cycling, sometimes offer the best way to see the world and appreciate the natural
                wonder and beauty of it all at a pace that suits you.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima nemo veritatis dolore consequatur? Debitis magni dolorem illo dolor dignissimos nulla sed corporis possimus eos ratione laboriosam earum consequuntur nesciunt voluptas, omnis, molestiae id odit. Cumque perspiciatis, soluta est impedit dolores at ab rerum qui repellat facere a repudiandae adipisci molestiae, sed, illum deserunt reiciendis. Illo tempore quaerat vel, vitae fuga numquam facilis voluptatem ipsa doloremque quia voluptatum? Ducimus ratione officiis molestiae deleniti. Beatae totam esse culpa aliquam, officiis quia modi asperiores dolores cumque magnam doloremque voluptatibus architecto fuga natus eius saepe reiciendis ea eligendi animi! Fugiat veritatis culpa temporibus eligendi.</p></article>
            
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>    

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        /*!
        * @preserve
        *
        * Readmore.js jQuery plugin
        * Author: @jed_foster
        * Project home: http://jedfoster.github.io/Readmore.js
        * Licensed under the MIT license
        *
        * Debounce function from http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function
        */
        !function(t){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],t):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=t(require("jquery")):t(jQuery)}(function(t){"use strict";function e(t,e,i){var o;return function(){var n=this,a=arguments,s=function(){o=null,i||t.apply(n,a)},r=i&&!o;clearTimeout(o),o=setTimeout(s,e),r&&t.apply(n,a)}}function i(t){var e=++h;return String(null==t?"rmjs-":t)+e}function o(t){var e=t.clone().css({height:"auto",width:t.width(),maxHeight:"none",overflow:"hidden"}).insertAfter(t),i=e.outerHeight(),o=parseInt(e.css({maxHeight:""}).css("max-height").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g,""),10),n=t.data("defaultHeight");e.remove();var a=o||t.data("collapsedHeight")||n;t.data({expandedHeight:i,maxHeight:o,collapsedHeight:a}).css({maxHeight:"none"})}function n(t){if(!d[t.selector]){var e=" ";t.embedCSS&&""!==t.blockCSS&&(e+=t.selector+" + [data-readmore-toggle], "+t.selector+"[data-readmore]{"+t.blockCSS+"}"),e+=t.selector+"[data-readmore]{transition: height "+t.speed+"ms;overflow: hidden;}",function(t,e){var i=t.createElement("style");i.type="text/css",i.styleSheet?i.styleSheet.cssText=e:i.appendChild(t.createTextNode(e)),t.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(i)}(document,e),d[t.selector]=!0}}function a(e,i){this.element=e,this.options=t.extend({},r,i),n(this.options),this._defaults=r,this._name=s,this.init(),window.addEventListener?(window.addEventListener("load",c),window.addEventListener("resize",c)):(window.attachEvent("load",c),window.attachEvent("resize",c))}var s="readmore",r={speed:100,collapsedHeight:200,heightMargin:16,moreLink:'<a href="#">Read More</a>',lessLink:'<a href="#">Close</a>',embedCSS:!0,blockCSS:"display: block; width: 100%;",startOpen:!1,blockProcessed:function(){},beforeToggle:function(){},afterToggle:function(){}},d={},h=0,c=e(function(){t("[data-readmore]").each(function(){var e=t(this),i="true"===e.attr("aria-expanded");o(e),e.css({height:e.data(i?"expandedHeight":"collapsedHeight")})})},100);a.prototype={init:function(){var e=t(this.element);e.data({defaultHeight:this.options.collapsedHeight,heightMargin:this.options.heightMargin}),o(e);var n=e.data("collapsedHeight"),a=e.data("heightMargin");if(e.outerHeight(!0)<=n+a)return this.options.blockProcessed&&"function"==typeof this.options.blockProcessed&&this.options.blockProcessed(e,!1),!0;var s=e.attr("id")||i(),r=this.options.startOpen?this.options.lessLink:this.options.moreLink;e.attr({"data-readmore":"","aria-expanded":this.options.startOpen,id:s}),e.after(t(r).on("click",function(t){return function(i){t.toggle(this,e[0],i)}}(this)).attr({"data-readmore-toggle":s,"aria-controls":s})),this.options.startOpen||e.css({height:n}),this.options.blockProcessed&&"function"==typeof this.options.blockProcessed&&this.options.blockProcessed(e,!0)},toggle:function(e,i,o){o&&o.preventDefault(),e||(e=t('[aria-controls="'+this.element.id+'"]')[0]),i||(i=this.element);var n=t(i),a="",s="",r=!1,d=n.data("collapsedHeight");n.height()<=d?(a=n.data("expandedHeight")+"px",s="lessLink",r=!0):(a=d,s="moreLink"),this.options.beforeToggle&&"function"==typeof this.options.beforeToggle&&this.options.beforeToggle(e,n,!r),n.css({height:a}),n.on("transitionend",function(i){return function(){i.options.afterToggle&&"function"==typeof i.options.afterToggle&&i.options.afterToggle(e,n,r),t(this).attr({"aria-expanded":r}).off("transitionend")}}(this)),t(e).replaceWith(t(this.options[s]).on("click",function(t){return function(e){t.toggle(this,i,e)}}(this)).attr({"data-readmore-toggle":n.attr("id"),"aria-controls":n.attr("id")}))},destroy:function(){t(this.element).each(function(){var e=t(this);e.attr({"data-readmore":null,"aria-expanded":null}).css({maxHeight:"",height:""}).next("[data-readmore-toggle]").remove(),e.removeData()})}},t.fn.readmore=function(e){var i=arguments,o=this.selector;return e=e||{},"object"==typeof e?this.each(function(){if(t.data(this,"plugin_"+s)){var i=t.data(this,"plugin_"+s);i.destroy.apply(i)}e.selector=o,t.data(this,"plugin_"+s,new a(this,e))}):"string"==typeof e&&"_"!==e[0]&&"init"!==e?this.each(function(){var o=t.data(this,"plugin_"+s);o instanceof a&&"function"==typeof o[e]&&o[e].apply(o,Array.prototype.slice.call(i,1))}):void 0}});
    </script>

    <script>
        $('article').readmore();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it helps you can mark the answer as "Accepted Answer" if you want.